# Find file name using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to automate a process that will update a table in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

I am getting the file from a client in csv format with about 20 columns of data. I need to import the file into a table in the database when it is in a particular folder. If it is there, I need to do the import and then move the file from the base folder to a `Processed` folder.

I have done the import routine to drop the original table, create a new one, and import the data into the table.

I have searched for how to determine a file name in a particular folder with a particular extension and have not found anything that will assist me.

I also tried to do a move of the file(independent of the stored procedure) and I think I am missing something.  Here is what I tried without success:

```
    declare @sql varchar (100)
    set @sql = 'move E:\Data\check.csv E:\Data\Processed\ /Y'
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @SQL, NO_OUTPUT 
    go
```

TIA

Comment: I found the error on the move.  I tried it in DOS and found that you need to identify the full file name in order to move it.  Which leaves me with the same problem, if I cannot find the file name then I cannot import and I cannot move.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following stored procedure to list the files in a given path:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp__ListFiles_xml] (
    @path varchar(8000),
    @xmldata xml output
)
as
begin
    DECLARE @ProcName varchar(255) = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID);

    declare @DirLines table (
        RowNum int identity(1,1) not null,
        line varchar(8000)
    );

    declare @DirCommand varchar(8000) = 'dir /A:-D /n "'+@path+'"';

    insert into @DirLines
        exec xp_cmdshell @DirCOmmand;

    declare @DirName varchar(8000) = (select SUBSTRING(line, 15, 8000) from @DirLines where RowNum = 4);

    delete from @DirLines
    where line is null or isnumeric(LEFT(line, 2)) = 0;

    set @xmldata = (
        select substring(line, 40, 255) as FileName,
               cast(replace(substring(line, 21, 18), ',', '') as bigint) as FileSize,
               cast(left(line, 20) as DateTime) as CreationDateTime,
               @DirName as DirName
        from @DirLines
        for xml raw('Dir'), type
       )

    return;
end;  -- usp__ListFiles_xml
```

You can select the results into a table, find the file you need, and then continue your load from there by doing:

```
declare @xmldata xml;

exec usp__ListFiles_xml @FileTemplate, @xmldata output;

declare @Files table (
     FileName varchar(255),
     FileSize bigint,
     CreationDateTime DateTime,
     DirName varchar(8000)
    );
insert into @Files
    select T.c.value('@FileName', 'varchar(255)') as FileName,
           T.c.value('@FileSize', 'bigint') as FileSize,
           T.c.value('@CreationDateTime', 'datetime') as CreationDateTime,
           T.c.value('@DirName', 'varchar(8000)') as DirName
    from @xmldata.nodes('Dir') as T(c);
```

Comment: This is very cool.  I may have other files in the directory but I am only concerned with the .csv files.  Is it better to limit the file at the creation stage in the SP ups_Listfiles_xml or afterward when I have the @FileName and have a case if like *.csv?

Comment: In the usp_ListFiles_xml you have a _spcalls insert into _spcalls(spname, args)
        SELECT @ProcName,
               (''''+coalesce(@path, '')+''''                                                             I am getting an error when I call this usp.
               );

Comment: @TimVavra . . . Oops.  I didn't sanitize the code completely.  That's a table I use to keep track of all my stored procedure calls.